# How to Get All Contract Addresses For Token From CoinMarketCap API?

Tags: token, coinmarketcap

CoinMarketCap provides an API to get listing information (https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest)

It returns a listing (token/coin) information. If that's a token, it will fill the `platform` field with an object describing platform.

E.g.

```json
{
  ...,
  platform: {
      id: 1027,
      name: 'Ethereum',
      symbol: 'ETH',
      slug: 'ethereum',
      token_address: '0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2'
    },
  ...

}
```

But wrapped tokens have many contracts for different platforms. Take Wrapped ETH as an example: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/weth/

The API returns info on Ethereum network only. Polygon, for example, has WETH as well, and it has a different token address.

Is there a way to fetch platforms list for a token from Coinmarketcap API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following endpoint returns a list of contract addresses

https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV2CryptocurrencyInfo